# How to read empty and filled rows then delete filled rows if value is 0?

Tags: vba, excel

I am having difficulty writing a code that reads empty rows (gaps) and reads filled (Title) rows from Column `C` but only deletes empty rows with titles, not empty rows (gaps).

If a code can be created to read of Column `C` for row titles and empty gaps; or just gaps which do not have any titles in Column `C`. Then if a row with the title is empty from Column `D` until `L` and `n/m` means nothing which means it's empty, that row should be deleted but not removing the gaps. This picture shows the formatting of the file and the fourth line needs to be removed. Any help would be appreciated

[image]

My code with some suede code. I am a little confused how I would go about this..

```
   Dim WS As Worksheet
     For Each WS In Sheets
     WS.Activate

       Dim n As Long
         Dim nlast As Long
         Dim rw As Range
         Set rw = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
         nlast = rw.count

         For n = nlast To 9 Step -1
          If (rw.Cells(n, 3).Value = "") Then
          keep
          ElseIf (rw.Cells(n, 3).Value = text) Then
          keep but
          Else (rw.Cells(n, 4).Value = "" And rw.Cells(n, 5).Value = "" And rw.Cells(n, 6).Value = "" And rw.Cells(n, 7).Value = "" And rw.Cells(n, 8).Value = "" And rw.Cells(n, 9).Value = "" And rw.Cells(n, 10).Value = "" And rw.Cells(n, 11).Value = "") Then
          rw.Rows(n).Delete

             End If
         Next n
         Next WS
     End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close. Here is the fixed code:

```
 Sub Test()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim n As Long
Dim nlast As Long


For Each WS In Sheets

nlast = WS.UsedRange.Rows(WS.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

    For n = nlast To 9 Step -1
        If WS.Cells(n, 3).Value <> "" And WS.Cells(n, 4).Value = "" And WS.Cells(n, 5).Value = "" And _
        WS.Cells(n, 6).Value = "" And WS.Cells(n, 7).Value = "" And WS.Cells(n, 8).Value = "" And _
        WS.Cells(n, 9).Value = "" And WS.Cells(n, 10).Value = "" And WS.Cells(n, 11).Value = "" Then

        WS.Rows(n).EntireRow.Delete

        End If
    Next n
Next WS
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, this macro isn't deleting anything. The title rows are still there...I think I wasn't clear. If in column `C` there is a gap which is an empty row without a title in Column `C` then that row can remain and not get deleted but if there is a row that begins with a title in Column `C` then it should ONLY be deleted if that row is empty between Column `D` and `L`

Comment: @MTBthePRO - Does your `UsedRange` start in column A?  If not, you will need to adjust all the column numbers to refer to the correct columns within the `UsedRange`.  (As I said yesterday, it is better to work on the worksheet rather than the `UsedRange`.)

Comment: @YowE3K well I was under the influence that `UsedRange` are a must for nLast because the last row needs to be determined.

Comment: @MTBthePRO what value does msgbox(nlast) return?

Comment: @MTBthePRO Just updated my code, see if it works better

Comment: The value of `nlast` won't be an issue as currently written (before the last edit) - if the first cell in `UsedRange` was C6 and the last row of data was row 55 then `nlast` will be 50, and `rw.Cells(50, 3)` will be referring to the worksheet row 55.  The issue will be the column, because `rw.Cells(50, 3)` will be referring to cell E55.

Comment: @YowE3K I understand your logic, but how would I resolve this without seing the underlying data? I would usually do nlast + 5 if I know that I have 5 empty cells before my data.

Comment: In my answer to this sort of question yesterday, I said to use `nlast = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row` to get the last worksheet row.  (That was within a `With WS` block.)  And then I used `.Cells` everywhere (so that it referred to the worksheet) rather than `rw.Cells`.  That allowed the safe use of `.Cells(n, 3).Value` to mean the value in worksheet column `C` in worksheet row `n`.

Comment: `nlast` returns 20 @YowE3K

Comment: @VBAPete what is `.Rows.Count, "A"` is it suppose to be `n.Rows.Count, "A"`

Comment: @MTBthePRO - Do you have anything in column A (or B)?

Comment: @YowE3K no, every sheet starts from `C4`

Comment: @MTBthePRO I see, try the updated code with YowE3K's suggestion

Comment: You will need to include a `With WS` block, or change `nlast = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row` to `nlast = WS.UsedRange.Rows(WS.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row`.

Comment: Updated the code again. I tested it now and it worked for me :)

Comment: it works. Thanks to both of you for helping out. Really appreciate it.  @VBAPete

Comment: My pleasure @MTBthePRO, glad to help.